# Can someone explain this to me? (HTML CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div's right now which are nicely bumped to eachother. Like there is no space between them (Vertically).

Right now I face this weird problem, that when I change the font from my `<h1> yoga 2 pro</h1>` element, it creates a space between my 2 div's which I have to solve by using `margin-top: -10px;`But I think this is not the clean way.

PS: The `<h1>` does fit in the div, and there is it doesn't show outside the div.

Anyone know whats wrong?

```css
.navmenu
{
    background-color:#2c2c2c;
    height: 60px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: -14px;
}
        
.mainmenu
{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.mainmenu ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
        
.mainmenu li
{
    display: inline; 
    padding-left: 20px;
}
        
.midden
{
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    width: 97%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: white;
}
        
.midden img
{
    float:left;
}
        
.midden h1
{
    color:black;
    font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navmenu">
    <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li>laptops en Ultrabooks</li>
        <li>Tablets</li>
        <li>Dekstops en alles-in-een computers</li>
        <li>Werkstations</li>
        <li>Servers en opslag</li>
        <li>Accessoires</li>
        <li>Aanbiedingen</li>
        <li>Diensten en garanties</li>
        <li>Waar verkrijgbaar</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="midden">
    <img src="images/laptop.png">
    <h1>Yoga 2 pro</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Add margin: 0 auto; for h1

Comment: What is style of .h1 class?

Comment: can you please show it in a fidlle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin: 0 X X X;` to your `h1` tag or add `margin-top: 0px`

The Xs in the first statement being `margin-right`, `margin-bottom`, `margin-left` respectively.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, I have to put margin-top: 0px; for that one too! Didn't know that thanks! Will mark your answer in 12 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can use `float: left` to `h1` element:

```css
.navmenu {
    background-color:#2c2c2c;
    height: 60px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: -14px;
}
.mainmenu {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.mainmenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.mainmenu li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.midden {
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    width: 97%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
.midden img {
    float:left;
}
.midden h1 {
    color:black;
    font-size: 75px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navmenu">
    <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li>laptops en Ultrabooks</li>
        <li>Tablets</li>
        <li>Dekstops en alles-in-een computers</li>
        <li>Werkstations</li>
        <li>Servers en opslag</li>
        <li>Accessoires</li>
        <li>Aanbiedingen</li>
        <li>Diensten en garanties</li>
        <li>Waar verkrijgbaar</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="midden">
    <img src="http://revolution52.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/blue-grunge-200x200.jpg">
     <h1>Yoga 2 pro</h1>

</div>
```